# SQLite PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY definition

Tags: sql, database, python-3.11, sqlite3-python

I think I do a failure in the tables definition for PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY.

The import and creation works fine in a sqlite3 database. No error message.

This is my declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE "contact" 
(
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "uniqueid" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "mod_time" TEXT,
    "mod_datetime" TEXT,
    "features_doorphone" TEXT,
    "setup" TEXT,
    "category" INTEGER,
    "pb_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("pb_id") REFERENCES "phonebook"("id_pb"),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id", "uniqueid", "pb_id")
);
```

But if I try to write values into the tables I get this error:

> IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed :
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:.._parser.py", line 107, in db_insert_phonebook
> cur.executemany("INSERT INTO contact(uniqueid, category, pb_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?);", args[1])
> sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: contact.id

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\.._parser.py", line 134, in <module>
    fritz_phone_parser(file_path)
  File "D:\.._parser.py", line 96, in fritz_phone_parser
    db_insert_phonebook(meta_date, contact_l, person_l, telephony_l, services_l, person_img_l)
  File "D:\.._parser.py", line 106, in db_insert_phonebook
    with db as cur:
  File "D:\.._parser.py", line 36, in __exit__
    self.rollback()
AttributeError: 'SQLite_db' object has no attribute 'rollback'
```

This are my python insert command:

```
def db_insert_phonebook(*args):
 
    with db as cur:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO phonebook(pb_name, pb_owner, pb_date_last_edit) VALUES(?, ?, ?);", args[0])
        print("Phonebook table filled") # pb_owner = pb_id

    with db as cur:
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO contact(uniqueid, category, pb_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?);", args[1])
```

My inserted values are all available. And if I define the table only with one single PRIMARY KEY the insert works without any error.

Definition works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE "contact" 
(
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "uniqueid" INTEGER,
    "mod_time" TEXT,
    "mod_datetime" TEXT,
    "features_doorphone" TEXT,
    "setup" TEXT,
    "category" INTEGER,
    "pb_id" INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("pb_id") REFERENCES "phonebook"("id_pb"),
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

I assume it have to do with my composite primary key definition. Any hints are very welcome. I have forgotten to note I work on a in-memory database.

Comment: You don’t appear to be inserting a value into contact.id. As this is part of the PK it is, by definition, not null

Comment: @NickW that’s right, but id is autoincrement. See my    second table definition, it work perfect with the same inserted data.

Comment: My understanding is that Sqlite doesn’t support autoincrement on composite primary keys - hence the error message that contact.id is null as it’s not autoincrement and you aren’t providing a value